# FGLRX driver crashes constantly

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, fglrx

I have an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5850 video card, and I have recently installed the fglrx driver on Ubuntu 14.04 to improve the performance, since the X.Org X Server driver was overloading the CPU even with simple tasks like dragging a window. However, ever since I installed fglrx, my computer keeps crashing and coming back to the login screen.

Here's the output of `dmesg` right after a crash:

```
[27851.587590] <3>[fglrx:__create_mapping] *ERROR* Can not get virtual address
[27851.587595] <3>[fglrx:__mc_heap_map_virtual_space] *ERROR* Failed to map the virtual space
[27851.587598] <3>[fglrx:mc_heap_map_virtual_space] *ERROR* Can not get virtual address
[27851.587600] <3>[fglrx:MCIL_GetVirtualAddressInDescriptor] *ERROR* Can not get the virtual address
```

Does anybody know how I could prevent this error from happening?

Thanks in advance!